# How to know which variable to optimize?

Tags: calculus

When we have a problem like the [corridor pipe problem](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.06/s/student2.html).
In [this solution](http://youtu.be/UtfmX5UZ3-o) he maximized the angle theta when my intuition was to minimize the side y.
Is there a general way to quickly identify which variable to optimize and whether we should maximize or minimize it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very problem dependent. When you have, say, the equation which governs the problem here starts the mathematical analysis and this is why knowledge in mathematics and applied mathematics is crucial in physics, engineering, finance,...

Soppose that your problem is a single nonlinear equation for a single unknown which has to be selected among other(in your case, the side or the angle) : this means that when you know the value of one of them, the value of all other are known (implicitely or explicitely). I think (I mean, I know) that the one I shall select is the one which makes the equation as linear as possible and avoids discontinuities. In the case you mention in your post, if the side is not selected, the best variable will not be the angle itself but its sine or whatever trigonometric function.

You address here basically the question of what I have been doing beside that in the last 53+ years.

I shall not dilute more my blabla; I could speak forever about this. I am still very concerned. If there is anything I could clarify, jus post.